# How to run Matlab computations in parallel

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, backgroundworker, background-process

I have Matlab .m script that sets and trains Neural network ("nn") using Matlab's Neural network toolbox. The script launches some GUI that shows trainig progress etc. The training of nn usually takes long time.

I'm doing these experiments on computer with 64 processor cores. I want to train several networks at the same time without having to run multiple Matlab sessions.
So I want to:

1. Start training of neural network
2. Modify script that creates network to create different one
3. Start training of modified network
4. Modify script to create yet another network...
5. Repeat steps 1-4 several times

The problem is that when I run the scrip it blocks Matlab terminal so I cannot do anything else until the script executes its last command - and that takes long. How can I run all those computations in parallel? I do have Matlab parallel toolbox.

---

### EDIT: Matlab bug??

**Update:** This problem seems to happen only on R2012a, looks like fixed on R2012b.

There is **very** strange error when I try command sequence recommended in [Edric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12948978/311865).
Here is my code:

```
 >> job = batch(c, @nn, 1, {A(:, 1:end -1), A(:, end)});
 >> wait(job);
 >> r = fetchOutputs(job)
 Error using parallel.Job/fetchOutputs (line 677)
 An error occurred during execution of Task with ID 1.

 Caused by:
    Error using nntraintool (line 35)
    Java is not available.
```

Here are the lines 27-37 of `nntraintool` (part of Matlab's Neural networks toolkit) where error originated:

```
if ~usejava('swing')
  if (nargin == 1) && strcmp(command,'check')
    result = false;
    result2 = false;
    return
  else

    disp('java used');
    error(message('nnet:Java:NotAvailable'));
  end
end
```

So it looks like the problem is that GUI (because Swing is not available) cannot be used when job is executed using `batch` command. The strange thing is that the `nn` function does not launch any GUI in it's current form. The error is caused by [train](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/train.html) that launches GUI by default but in `nn` I have switched that off:

```
net.trainParam.showWindow = false;
net = train(net, X, y);
```

More interestingly if the same `nn` function is launched normally (`>> nn(A(:, 1:end -1), A(:, end));`) it never enters the outer *if-then* statement of `nntraintool` on line 27 (I have checked that using debugger). So using the same function, the same arguments expression `~usejava('swing')` evaluates to `0` when command is launched normally but to 1 when launched using `batch`.

What do you think about this? **It looks like ugly Matlab or Neural networks toolbox bug** :(((

Comment: There's a bug report for nntraintool here http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/bugreports/861218 including a R2012a workaround. It's fixed in R2012b as you observe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Parallel Computing Toolbox, you can run up to 12 'local workers' to execute your scripts (to run more than that, you'd need to purchase additional [MATLAB Distributed Computing Server](http://www.mathworks.com/products/distriben/) licences). Given your workflow, the best thing might be to use the [BATCH](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/batch.html) command to submit a series of non-interactive jobs. Note that you will not be able to see any GUI from the workers. You might do something like this (using R2012a+ syntax):

```
c = parcluster('local'); % get the 'local' cluster object
job = batch(c, 'myNNscript'); % submit script for execution
% now edit 'myNNscript'
job2 = batch(c, 'myNNscript'); % submit script for execution
...
wait(job); load(job) % get the results
```

Note that the BATCH command automatically attaches a copy of the script to run to the job, so that you are free to make changes to it after submission.

Comment: There is **very** strange error when I try your recontamination. I have updated my question to show details. Please have a look on it and write what you think about it.

Comment: So I have found out that it is only problem of R2012a version. Looks like it works fine on R2012b.